# Modifying QuerySet result

Tags: django, slice, django-queryset

Is it possible to change some specific items in a QuerySet object? In my case i'm trying to slicing "title" fields with length more than 40 characters and append "..." at the end of field.

Comment: Are you trying to save those changes to the database or just display them on a page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing what you want.

The first is to use a Django filter.  So if you are looping through the items of your queryset and displaying them on a page use something like [truncatewords](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords).  You would use this like this in your template:

```
{% for item in queryset %}
    <h1>{{ item.title|truncatewords:3 }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

It doesn't look like there is a Django filter for truncating base on the number of characters. If you want to [write your own filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) it's not that hard to do.

The other option is to put a method on your model to do what you want.  Here is an example:

```
@property
def short_title(self):
    return '%s...' % self.title[:40]
```

You would then be able to reference this anywhere in your template as {{ object.short_title }}.

Comment: hi @sheats , can we added a new column field in the queryset ? I want to try add new value in the query set and looping using for loop return the value in the template.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding a new property 'adjusted_title' to each object

```
for item in your_query_set:
    if(len(item.title) > 40):
        item.adjusted_title = item.title[0:40] + "..."
```

Comment: This would work, but could mean an unnecessary loop through the queryset.  It's probably better to just put the logic in a method on the model like I suggested to save an unnecessary loop and in case the logic is needed somewhere else.